# Randomizing start point of Javascript Scrollbox plugin?

Tags: javascript

I have a set width/height div with an unordered list with 10 li tags, an img tag per li.

I have the images scrolling through vertically using Javascript Scrollbox.

When you land on the page I need to randomize which logo appears in the box first instead of the first li always showing first (and scrolling can continue as normal in order)

Is this possible? If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

HTML inside head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollbox.min.js"></script>
```

HTML inside body:

```
<div id="buslogos">
<p>Some of our participating businesses:</p>

<div id="buslogoscroll" class="scroll-img">
<ul>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/abshair-sm.gif" alt="Absolute Hair Inc"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/arena-sm.gif" alt="Arena Tavern"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/davebusters-sm.jpg" alt="Dave &amp; Buster's"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/dunkin-sm.gif" alt="Dunkin' Donuts"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/lazercity-sm.jpg" alt="Lazer City"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/marcos-sm.gif" alt="Marco's Pizza"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/mtimes-sm.gif" alt="Medieval Times"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/stars-sm.gif" alt="Stars and Strikes"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/tomchee-sm.gif" alt="Tom + Chee"></li>
  <li><img src="images/part-bus-logos/totalhealth-sm.jpg" alt="Total Health Spa"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('#buslogoscroll').scrollbox({
    linear: true,
    step: 1,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 40
  });
});
</script>
```

The jquery.scrollbox.min.js was downloaded from here:
https://github.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be helpful to show some code ([see here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Hi nthall, Thanks for the tip and I've added my code above. I have not tried anything as I'm so new to Javascript/Jquery I'm not sure where to start! 

I imagine that I'd need to add something inside the function at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, Let me know if you didn't understand anything.
[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/pexibajava/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox/master/jquery.scrollbox.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(function () {
  var arrSrc=["http://placehold.it/350x50",
             "http://placehold.it/350x60",
              "http://placehold.it/350x70",
              "http://placehold.it/350x80",
              "http://placehold.it/350x90"
             ];
  $('.first img').attr('src',arrSrc[Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0)]);
  $('#buslogoscroll').scrollbox({
    linear: true,
    step: 1,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 40
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="buslogos">
<p>Some of our participating businesses:</p>

<div id="buslogoscroll" class="scroll-img">
<ul>
  <li class="first"><img src=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x60"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x70"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x80"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x90"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really easy to understand. Unfortunately this isn't exactly what I needed, but it does seem an array is the right way to go?

If you look at my UL above I need, say, the 3rd li to be visible and then scroll to the 4th, 5th, etc. and back to 1st. THEN if you refresh the page it may start on the 5th li, then scroll to the 6th, 7th, and back to 1 and loop again.

Does that make sense?